# Passed argument/parameter in function is still being changed after removing the reference/alias

Tags: python

I've spent the last 2 hours on this and I've probably read every question on here relating to variables being passed to functions. My issue is the common one of the parameter/argument being affected by changes made inside the function, even though I have removed the reference/alias by using `variable_cloned = variable[:]` in the function to copy the contents across without the reference.

Here is the code:

```
def add_column(m):    
    #this should "clone" m without passing any reference on    
    m_cloned = m[:]
    for index, element in enumerate(m_cloned):
        # parameter m can be seen changing along with m_cloned even
        # though 'm' is not touched during this function except to 
        # pass it's contents onto 'm_cloned'        
        print "This is parameter 'm' during the for loop...", m
        m_cloned[index] += [0]
    print "This is parameter 'm' at end of for loop...", m    
    print "This is variable 'm_cloned' at end of for loop...", m_cloned
    print "m_cloned is m =", m_cloned is m, "implies there is no reference"
    return m_cloned

matrix = [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
print "\n"
print "Variable 'matrix' before function:", matrix
print "\n"
add_column(matrix)
print "\n"
print "Variable 'matrix' after function:", matrix
```

What I'm noticing is that the parameter 'm' in the function is changing as if is an alias of m_cloned - but as far as I can tell I have removed the alias with the first line of the function. Everywhere else I have looked online seems to suggest that this line will make sure there is no reference to parameter - but it's not working.

I'm sure I must have made a simple mistake but after 2 hours I don't think I'm going to find it.

Comment: "... even though I have removed the reference/alias by using variable_cloned = variable[:] in the function to copy the contents across without the reference." This makes `variable_cloned` refer to a separate list from `variable`, but the two lists will contain identical contents: references to your three (2-item) lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you need a deepcopy, instead of a shallow copy, which is what `[:]` gives you:

```
from copy import deepcopy
list2 = deepcopy(list1)
```

Here's a longer example comparing the two types of copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy

list1 = [[1], [1]]
list2 = list1[:]   # while id(list1) != id(list2), it's items have the same id()s
list3 = deepcopy(list1)

list1[0] += [3]

print list1
print list2
print list3
```

Outputs:

```
[[1, 3], [1]]  # list1
[[1, 3], [1]]  # list2
[[1], [1]]     # list3 - unaffected by reference-madness
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I would never have got there on my own. I'm looking at [link](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) which seems to somewhat explain the differences between deep and shallow copy but I'm not sure what it means practically - should I do deepcopy every time I pass a variable to a function?

Comment: @FiveAlive Not necessarily.  Sometimes you want to keep references to "child" objects.  Sometimes it doesn't matter (when dealing with immutable "children"), since things like strings/ints cannot change values, but instead are replaced by new copies, which would not be a problem in your case.  "Knowing" is half the battle (they say), now that you know, I'm sure you'll pay closer attention next time to what you need.